# How to not show overflow menu in the touch a hardware key

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-hardware-keyboard

I am using toolbar, add option item in `OnCreateOptionsMenu()` and set  `showAsAction="always"` so, 3-dot overflow icon does not show. is good work,
but show overflow(popup) when i touch the hardware menu key.

I use a hardware key, for other function. How to not show overflow menu in the touch the hardware key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found. overflow occurred in KeyUp

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
        work(); //handle
        return true;
    }

    //not menu key
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

works for me